# Grafana variable query is not retrieving all endpoints' from a Prometheus pod target (but gets some of them)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks, grafana-templating

While maintaining a simple set of a Grafana and a Prometheus pod, plus a few others, within a cluster on Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS)—I ran into an issue where a "instance" variable query set up in Grafana only retrieves any data from several, out of 52, VM's/instances in a Prometheus scrape job.

There are a couple other Grafana variables that can arbitrarily nest / be nested inside of the "instance" variable, but switching the order of them did nothing.
[image: the variables, including "instance" and "environment" which do not depend on each other and I tried switching]

To elaborate, this is bizarre because I am getting perfect data for 11 out of the 52 VM's/instances while the others are not being populated in the "instance" Grafana variable as they should be. Maybe this is a backend issue, but have not found any oddities while probing around with `kubectl`.

Thank you!

Comment: can you confirm if all the 52 instances are sending the windows_iis_requests_total metric?

Comment: You nailed it on the head @rohatgisanat ! Even though all of the VMs/instances are up and running, each missing VM's Prometheus instance didn't contain the metric "windows_iis_requests_total" that was scanned for by the Grafana variable query and therefore was not included in the Grafana variable dropdown. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

All the 52 instances were not sending the windows_iis_requests_total metric.Hence the label_values gave the incomplete response.